# Laravel 9 laravel associate polymorphic relations bookmarks

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, relationship

I have this `Bookmark` model

```
public function bookmarkable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

and in my `User` model

```
public function bookmarks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bookmark::class);
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

and the `Post` model

```
public function bookmarks()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Bookmark::class, 'bookmarkable');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I want to create a new `$bookmark` and associate a `$post` with that bookmark

the bookmarks table has the columns `bookmarkable_type`, `bookmarkable_id` and `user_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause **morphTo** extends **belongsTo**

U can use like this

```
$post = Post::first()// the post u want add to bookmark
$newBookmark = new Bookmark([]);
$newBookmark->name="lorem ipsum";
$newBookmark->bookmarkable()->associate($post);
$newBookmark->user()->associate($post->user);
$newBookmark->save();
```

See the class docs:
https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphTo.html